# Why document.URL not showing the curreny url?

Tags: jquery

cam you please tell me 
Why document.URL not showing the curreny url 
Correct url :http://jsfiddle.net/PWEAR/20/
Showing :http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/PWEAR/20/

```
 console.log(document.URL + ': ' + CheckUrl(document.URL));
    alert("http://ca.firstrail.com: " + CheckUrl("http://ca.firstrail.com"));
    alert("http://fr.firstrail.com: " + CheckUrl("http://fr.firstrail.com"));

    function CheckUrl(url) {
        var rx = new RegExp('http://(ca|fr)');
        var result = rx.exec(url);
        return result && result[1] || 'no fr or ca';
    }
```

Comment: _Correct url_......what do you mean by this? to me its working fine.

Comment: What browser and version are you using? This may generate issues

Comment: chorme or firebox not working

Answer (score 1):

That's because jsFiddle uses iframes for the windows, so it *does* show the correct URL, for that frame.

Try it outside jsFiddle and it should work, and remember that you should never set `document.URL`, that's what `window.location` is for

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because jsFiddle's mechanisms. The script is not embedded inside the page, it's inside a frame.

If you're using chrome, you should be able to check it yourself:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try `window.location.href` instead `document.URL`

it seems like Fiddle uses the iframe so the `document.URL` brings the iframes urls